# How can I get this code to work for mixed character/number or date fields?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I don't really know anything about coding, but found this useful code on a forum, but it's not working for any fields that have numbers or dates. I need the code to work for fields that have numbers and characters mixed and also for date fields. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub cboAmount_AfterUpdate()
Dim myAmount As String
myAmount = "Select * from Records where ([Amount] = '" & Me.cboAmount & "')"
Me.Records_subform.Form.RecordSource = myAmount
Me.Records_subform.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

Basically I have a search form that populates the search results in the attached subform so that searched records can be edited quickly from the search form.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `[Amount]` is numeric, you cannot put single quotes around it... It should look like this:

```
([Amount] = " & Me.cboAmount & ")"
```

if it's a date field, then you use the `#` sign:

```
([MyDate] = #" & Me.DateBox & "#)"
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for my date fields. How would I make it work for fields where I have numbers, letters, and special characters? For example: I have a reference number field where the inputs look like this --> #H392

Comment: Then do it the way you did it with the single quotes. Those are used for string fields, which is what you are describing. The only exception is if your string value has a single quote in it, then you have to change that single quote to 2 single quotes.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for any fields that include numbers. Thank you for the help with the Date fields. That is huge!

Comment: It works like that for everyone else. Maybe your field that has numbers is defined as a string by mistake.

Comment: I changed the fields from longtext to shorttext and it is working now! Thank you so much!